# Nested for-loop: why is the condition stated in for() ineffective?

Tags: c, for-loop

So for the code below, I want the C program to show odd numbers (that are not multiples of 3) between 1 and 999, with 9 in one line.

```
1   5   7   11   13   17   19   23   25

29   31   .. and so on.
```

Below is the code that I used. While I did figure out how to make it work - the `if (i >=999) break;` line helped, I don't understand why `i` goes over 999 if that break line didn't exist. In other words, the condition `i < 999` in both loops is ineffective.

Could someone help me understand why this acts this way?

I'm using Microsoft Visual Studio 2005 in class.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void main(void)
{
    int i, j;

    for(i = 1; i < 999; i++)
    {
        for(j = 0; i < 999, j< 9; i++, j++)
        {
            if (i%2 == 0 || i%3 == 0) {
                j = j-1;
                if (i >=999) break;
                continue;
            }
            printf("%-3d ", i);
            if (j == 8) break;
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: Please review the answers given below.

Answer (score 1):

Because you original code was a bit convoluted, I thought it would be easiest to answer your question by starting from scratch.  Here is a C code which achieves what you want, and it is a lot simpler than the OP:

```
void main(void) {
    int counter = 0;

    for (int i=0; i < 1000; ++i) {
        if (i % 2 != 0 && i % 3 != 0) {  // if not even (i.e. odd) AND not divisible by 3
            if (counter == 9) {          // start a new line for each 9 numbers
                printf("\n");
                counter = 0;             // reset the counter
            }
            printf("%-3d ", i);
            ++counter;                   // increment counter for each new number
        }
    }
}
```

I don't think you need or should have a double `for` loop in the solution.  And the conditions you have in the `for` loops also appear very complex.  This solution makes one pass over all numbers between 0 and 999 and generates the desired output.

Comment: @Himanshu Right you are.  I can't vote you up, but I will next time you post.  Thanks for pointing this out.

Answer (score 1):

An easy way is to

```
int numbers_in_line=0;
for(int i=1;i<=999;i++)
{
   if(i%2 && i%3) // not divisible by 2 as well as 3.
   {
      printf("%d ",i);
      numbers_in_line++;       // printed one number more
      if(numbers_in_line==9) 
      {
         printf("\n");
         numbers_in_line=0;  //reset for next line
      }
   }
}
```

In your code you can easily use a `count` variable to remember how many number you printed. That's it.

One thing in `if(i%2==0 || i%3==0)` now if for i=6 it will print it but it shouldn't. Clearly make it `if(i%2!=0 && i%3!=0)`

Another thing from your code there are few things clear,

1. Know how `,` works.(As mentioned in other answers)
2. Use simple logic not the negation of it..(The if mentioned)
3. Why are you keep decreasing as well increasing j. It's sole purpose is to keep track of number you have put in a line. So either decrease / increase it then reset to 9/0 as per your requirement respectively. Think this way you are never removing a number you have printed in a line so why decrease?

Comment: upvoted for pointing out the or/and test problem, but prefer Tim's variable naming.

Comment: @BrianTiffin.: Thank you. Yes the variable naming is terrible. But the OP's code has many other problems too.

Comment: Agree.  :-)  ct beats the i and j, at least.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in the condition of the for loop. There are two conditions `i < 999, j < 9.`

But it checks for only the last condition.

You want to change it to `for(j = 0; i < 999 && j< 9; i++, j++)` to check for both conditions

Comment: Your solution may be correct but your second sentence is dead wrong - that's not how the comma operator works. `a,b` evaluates `a` then `b` but the _result_ of the whole thing is `b` and `b` alone.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the expression carefully. `i < 999 , j < 9` . Here, first `i < 999` will get evaluated and after that `j < 9`. But, the result of the whole expression will be result of `j < 9` alone. Look at the code snippet for more **clarification:**

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int flag = (0,0);
    printf("%i ",flag);

    flag = (0,1);
    printf("%i ",flag);

    flag = (1,0);
    printf("%i ",flag);

    flag = (1,1);
    printf("%i ",flag);
}
```

**Output:**
0
1
0
1

And as mentioned in your code, if the value of **i** = 999, then the value of **j** comes out as `-1`, which becomes `0` on next iteration and similarly the value of **i** get increased by one. Therefore, the result of `i < 999` comes as `0 or false` and of `j < 9` comes as `1 or true`.

Since, the original expression was `i < 999 , j < 9`, which becomes `0,1` and from the above code we can see, it returns `1 or true`, which result it to further carry out the iterations.

Answer (score 0):

The condition in your inner for loop:

```
for(j = 0; i < 999, j< 9; i++, j++) {
    // ...
}
```

Is `i < 999, j< 9` which uses the often misunderstood comma operator.  The way that expression gets evaluated is:

- `i < 999` is evaluated, then the result is ignored (effectively, this part of the expression is a nop since there are no side effects)
- `j < 9` is evaluated and that is the result of the expression

If you want to use both condition in the expression, you want to use the logical And operator:

```
 i < 999 && j < 9
```

However, since `i` isn't modified in the inner loop, there's no reason to check it in that loop's condition - the outer loop will prevent the inner loop from being executed when `i < 999` fails.

Comment: Suggest to add it's not *in general* a *nop* because it actually *is* evaluated, so *side effects* would occur. It's effectively a *nop* here because this expression doesn't cause any *side effects*.